# ajax error "error loading page' using document.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a problem which is really perplexing me.  Simple to describe.  When I hit a button to submit a form I call a script which does a lot of stuff and then when done it heads the user's browser off to myPage2.  As soon as the user clicks the button, (i believe) AJAX very briefly displays the "error loading page" dialog box, closes that down and then starts displaying the new page.  No big deal, but it looks bad.  I've tried to bind to the onsubmit button --  no help.  I've tried Firebug/net to see what's going on.  I'm not very good with Firebug.  Never-the-less, the net/xhr doesn't display anything.  Problem is only on IOS/Safari and mobile/Chrome.   Any ideas greatly appreciated!!

```
<form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return buildFt();" >
    <div id="submitBtnWrap">
    <input type="submit"  value="Get Info!" data-inline="true"/>
    </div>
 </form>

 <script>document.location.href='indexShow.html';
 </script.
```

Comment: You may try to post the relevant code on your question.

Comment: Add `data-ajax=false` to form, and use `$.mobile.changePage()` to move to another page, not window.location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
window.location = "indexShow.html";
```

I guess this should be at the end of your buildFlight() function, but that's all what I can tell with the info you posted. Also, be sure that the html that you're accessing is at the same site level that the one where you're running the script, otherwise, you will need to pass an absolute url to the window.location function, something like:

```
window.location="http://www.mysite.com/indexShow.html";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: OK.  Thanks for your comments.  I've not tried window.location yet.  Yes, it is at the same site level, otherwise, I don't think it would work at all.  I tried a bunch of jQuery and jQuery Mile pagechange options and none of them helped.  I thought window.location was depricated quite a while back.....?